# Optimize query to find top N users who commented on a post

Tags: postgresql, optimization, performance, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-performance

## Problem

Trying to find the **most efficient query** to retrieve the top N (5 in the examples) users who have commented on a post, where a user is considered 'top' if they have the most followers. The query optimizer does not seem to be choosing the correct path.

## Tables (Postgres v9.4.4)

#### user_account (40k records)

```
CREATE TABLE user_account (
  user_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
);
```

#### following (13k records)

```
CREATE TABLE following (
  follower_user_id TEXT,
  followed_user_id TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (followed_user_id, follower_user_id)
);
```

#### follower_count_mv (10.5k records with only 5 users having > 1 follower)

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW follower_count_mv AS
SELECT followed_user_id AS user_id, COUNT(*)::int AS follower_count
FROM following
WHERE deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY user_id;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX follower_count_mv_user_id_idx ON follower_count_mv (user_id);
CREATE INDEX follower_count_mv_follower_count_idx ON follower_count_mv (follower_count);
```

#### user_post_comment (13.4k records but the majority are on 3 posts)

```
CREATE TABLE user_post_comment (
  comment_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id TEXT,
  post_id TEXT
)
CREATE INDEX user_post_comment_user_id_idx ON user_post_comment (user_id);
CREATE INDEX user_post_comment_post_id_idx ON user_post_comment (post_id);
```

## Queries I've tried

#### 1) The most natural choice: join the tables and sort

```
SELECT user_account.*
FROM user_account
JOIN follower_count_mv ON (user_account.user_id = follower_count_mv.user_id)
JOIN user_post_comment ON (user_account.user_id = user_post_comment.user_id)
WHERE user_post_comment.post_id = '26c72242-7e3b-4982-92c5-021b622d7ecd'
ORDER BY follower_count DESC LIMIT 5;
```

This is what I originally had, but the query optimizer seems to have a hard time figuring out the best way to execute this. Something to do with the data distribution perhaps?

```
Limit  (cost=0.99..117.00 rows=5 width=580) (actual time=0.082..148.688 rows=2 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.99..12136.14 rows=523 width=580) (actual time=0.081..148.687 rows=2 loops=1)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.57..6875.61 rows=1570 width=78) (actual time=0.049..148.624 rows=2 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan Backward using follower_count_mv_follower_count_idx on follower_count_mv  (cost=0.29..383.25 rows=10483 width=41) (actual time=0.011..1.904 rows=10483 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using user_post_comment_user_id_idx on user_post_comment  (cost=0.29..0.61 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=0 loops=10483)
                    Index Cond: ((user_id)::text = (follower_count_mv.user_id)::text)
                    Filter: ((post_id)::text = '26c72242-7e3b-4982-92c5-021b622d7ecd'::text)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 0
        ->  Index Scan using user_account_pkey on user_account  (cost=0.41..3.34 rows=1 width=576) (actual time=0.029..0.030 rows=1 loops=2)
              Index Cond: ((user_id)::text = (follower_count_mv.user_id)::text)
Planning time: 4.172 ms
Execution time: 148.763 ms
```

It appears to loop 10483 times ... why?

#### 2) #1 without specifying a limit (apparently makes it faster...)

```
Sort  (cost=6406.46..6407.76 rows=523 width=580) (actual time=14.574..14.574 rows=2 loops=1)
  Sort Key: follower_count_mv.follower_count
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=799.36..6382.84 rows=523 width=580) (actual time=11.633..14.545 rows=2 loops=1)
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=798.95..1122.31 rows=1570 width=78) (actual time=11.590..14.469 rows=2 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: ((follower_count_mv.user_id)::text = (user_post_comment.user_id)::text)
              ->  Seq Scan on follower_count_mv  (cost=0.00..202.83 rows=10483 width=41) (actual time=0.005..1.168 rows=10483 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=773.89..773.89 rows=2005 width=37) (actual time=11.448..11.448 rows=2005 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 136kB
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on user_post_comment  (cost=87.82..773.89 rows=2005 width=37) (actual time=1.211..11.040 rows=2005 loops=1)
                          Recheck Cond: ((post_id)::text = '26c72242-7e3b-4982-92c5-021b622d7ecd'::text)
                          Heap Blocks: exact=105
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on user_post_comment_post_id_idx  (cost=0.00..87.32 rows=2005 width=0) (actual time=1.196..1.196 rows=2005 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: ((post_id)::text = '26c72242-7e3b-4982-92c5-021b622d7ecd'::text)
        ->  Index Scan using user_account_pkey on user_account  (cost=0.41..3.34 rows=1 width=576) (actual time=0.034..0.035 rows=1 loops=2)
              Index Cond: ((user_id)::text = (follower_count_mv.user_id)::text)
Planning time: 1.935 ms
Execution time: 14.719 ms
```

#### 3) The optimal (but messy) way (that I've been able to find)

```
SELECT user_account.*
FROM user_account
JOIN follower_count_mv ON (user_account.user_id = follower_count_mv.user_id)
JOIN user_post_comment ON (user_account.user_id = user_post_comment.user_id)
WHERE user_post_comment.post_id = '26c72242-7e3b-4982-92c5-021b622d7ecd'
AND user_account.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM follower_count_mv ORDER BY follower_count DESC LIMIT 5)
ORDER BY follower_count DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Using a subquery to calculate the top N user IDs first seems to force the optimizer to do a more efficient calculation.

```
Limit  (cost=44.87..44.88 rows=1 width=580) (actual time=0.588..0.588 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=44.87..44.88 rows=1 width=580) (actual time=0.587..0.587 rows=2 loops=1)
         Sort Key: follower_count_mv.follower_count
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.52..44.86 rows=1 width=580) (actual time=0.358..0.571 rows=2 loops=1)
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.23..44.47 rows=1 width=654) (actual time=0.116..0.405 rows=5 loops=1)
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.95..42.81 rows=5 width=613) (actual time=0.081..0.243 rows=5 loops=1)
                           ->  HashAggregate  (cost=0.53..0.58 rows=5 width=37) (actual time=0.028..0.030 rows=5 loops=1)
                                 Group Key: ("ANY_subquery".user_id)::text
                                 ->  Subquery Scan on "ANY_subquery"  (cost=0.29..0.52 rows=5 width=37) (actual time=0.014..0.019 rows=5 loops=1)
                                       ->  Limit  (cost=0.29..0.47 rows=5 width=41) (actual time=0.013..0.018 rows=5 loops=1)
                                             ->  Index Scan Backward using follower_count_mv_follower_count_idx on follower_count_mv follower_count_mv_1  (cost=0.29..383.25 rows=10483 width=41) (actual time=0.013..0.018 rows=5 loops=1)
                           ->  Index Scan using user_account_pkey on user_account  (cost=0.41..8.43 rows=1 width=576) (actual time=0.041..0.041 rows=1 loops=5)
                                 Index Cond: ((user_id)::text = ("ANY_subquery".user_id)::text)
                     ->  Index Scan using follower_count_mv_user_id_idx on follower_count_mv  (cost=0.29..0.32 rows=1 width=41) (actual time=0.030..0.030 rows=1 loops=5)
                           Index Cond: ((user_id)::text = (user_account.user_id)::text)
               ->  Index Scan using user_post_comment_idx on user_post_comment  (cost=0.29..0.39 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=0.031..0.032 rows=0 loops=5)
                     Index Cond: ((user_id)::text = (user_account.user_id)::text)
                     Filter: ((post_id)::text = '26c72242-7e3b-4982-92c5-021b622d7ecd'::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 Planning time: 2.035 ms
 Execution time: 0.785 ms
```

#### 4) Add composite indexes and use subquery to get top 5 before joining

```
CREATE INDEX user_post_comment_post_id_user_id_idx ON user_post_comment (post_id, user_id);
CREATE INDEX follower_count_mv_user_id_follower_count_idx ON follower_count_mv (user_id, follower_count);

SELECT ua.*
FROM (
  SELECT user_id
  FROM user_post_comment pc
  JOIN follower_count_mv fc ON (pc.user_id = fc.user_id)
  WHERE post_id = '26c72242-7e3b-4982-92c5-021b622d7ecd'
  ORDER BY fc.follower_count DESC LIMIT 5
) sub
JOIN user_account ua ON (sub.user_id = ua.user_id)
JOIN follower_count_mv fc ON (sub.user_id = fc.user_id)
ORDER BY follower_count DESC LIMIT 5;

Limit  (cost=57.36..57.38 rows=5 width=579) (actual time=329.718..329.720 rows=2 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=57.36..57.38 rows=5 width=579) (actual time=329.717..329.717 rows=2 loops=1)
        Sort Key: fc.follower_count
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.40..57.31 rows=5 width=579) (actual time=0.118..329.709 rows=2 loops=1)
              Join Filter: ((pc.user_id)::text = (ua.user_id)::text)
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.98..40.54 rows=5 width=78) (actual time=0.089..329.657 rows=2 loops=1)
                    ->  Limit  (cost=0.70..18.92 rows=5 width=41) (actual time=0.067..329.618 rows=2 loops=1)
                          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.70..5721.98 rows=1570 width=41) (actual time=0.067..329.617 rows=2 loops=1)
                                ->  Index Scan Backward using follower_count_mv_follower_count_idx on follower_count_mv fc_1  (cost=0.29..383.25 rows=10483 width=41) (actual time=0.015..1.872 rows=10483 loops=1)
                                ->  Index Only Scan using user_post_comment_post_id_user_id_idx on user_post_comment pc  (cost=0.41..0.50 rows=1 width=37) (actual time=0.031..0.031 rows=0 loops=10483)
                                      Index Cond: ((post_id = '26c72242-7e3b-4982-92c5-021b622d7ecd'::text) AND (user_id = (fc_1.user_id)::text))
                                      Heap Fetches: 0
                    ->  Index Only Scan using follower_count_mv_user_id_follower_count_idx on follower_count_mv fc  (cost=0.29..4.31 rows=1 width=41) (actual time=0.019..0.019 rows=1 loops=2)
                          Index Cond: (user_id = (pc.user_id)::text)
                          Heap Fetches: 0
              ->  Index Scan using user_account_pkey on user_account ua  (cost=0.41..3.34 rows=1 width=575) (actual time=0.023..0.024 rows=1 loops=2)
                    Index Cond: ((user_id)::text = (fc.user_id)::text)
Planning time: 3.007 ms
Execution time: 331.744 ms
```

The estimated time goes down, but the execution time doubled. I don't understand the reason for this...

## Outstanding Questions

1. Why does #1 loop through the entire `follower_count_mv` table?
2. Why does removing `LIMIT` from #1 make the query optimizer choose a different query plan, where the estimated cost is higher, but the actual execution time is much much lower than #1?
3. Why is the query optimizer not smart enough to figure out it should do what query #3 does for query #1? Is the data distribution tripping it up?
4. If the database has a more normalized distribution of data, will query #1 perform the best? It's still not clear to me how the distribution affects the query plan.
5. What is the optimal query to use in this scenario, if not #3? #3 seems hacky to me; is there a way to make the query optimizer use the same plan as #2 for #1's query?

Comment: There's no `deleted_at` in your table definition. I guess you simplified the table and forgot to simplify the MV accordingly. Careful not so simplify too much or you might remove the problem by accident.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Better data types

`text` is a sub-optimal data type for key columns. It would be more efficient to use `integer`. Related:

- [Indexes: integer vs string performance if the number of nodes in the index is the same](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137945/indexes-integer-vs-string-performance-if-the-number-of-nodes-in-the-index-is-th/137949#137949)

`'26c72242-7e3b-4982-92c5-021b622d7ecd'` in your example looks like a UUID. If you need to use UUIDs, still don't store them as `text`. The appropriate data type would be **[`uuid`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-uuid.html)** - much more efficient. Details:

- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89429/would-index-lookup-be-noticeably-faster-with-char-vs-varchar-when-all-values-are/89433#89433)

#### Indexes

You only use single-column indexes. Since you need to optimize read performance for your query, add these two [**multicolumn indexes**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html):

```
CREATE INDEX fc_mv_user_id_follower_count_idx ON follower_count_mv (user_id, follower_count DESC);
CREATE INDEX upc_post_id_user_id_idx ON user_post_comment (post_id, user_id);
```

[@Ziggy](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/138160/3684) already mentioned the second.
The order of index columns is important:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field?lq=1)

Btree indexes can be scanned backwards at practically the same cost. But it's even slightly faster to use matching *descending* sort order. (There's a corner case with NULL values.)

#### Query

For a ***single post*** like in your examples it *won't get faster than this:*

```
SELECT ua.*
FROM  (
   SELECT user_id, fc.follower_count 
   FROM  (
      SELECT DISTINCT user_id
      FROM   user_post_comment
      WHERE  post_id = '26c72242-7e3b-4982-92c5-021b622d7ecd'
      ) pc
   JOIN   follower_count_mv fc USING (user_id)
   ORDER  BY fc.follower_count DESC
   LIMIT  5
   ) sub
JOIN   user_account ua USING (user_id)
ORDER  BY sub.follower_count DESC;
```

This is assuming that the same user can comment on the same post multiple times. It's cheapest to fold duplicates *before* joining to `follower_count_mv`.

And join to `follower_count_mv` directly. It's expensive and useless to use `user_account` as stepping stone.

Only join to `user_account` *after* reducing to the top 5.

You did not specify, but your queries have an outer `ORDER BY follower_count DESC`. I only include `follower_count` in the subquery for the outer sort.

---

If `(post_id, user_id)` is unique (users can only comment once on each post), simplify to:

```
SELECT ua.*
FROM  (
   SELECT user_id, fc.follower_count
   FROM   user_post_comment pc
   JOIN   follower_count_mv fc USING (user_id)
   WHERE  pc.post_id = '26c72242-7e3b-4982-92c5-021b622d7ecd'
   ORDER  BY fc.follower_count DESC
   LIMIT  5
   ) sub
JOIN   user_account ua USING (user_id)
ORDER  BY sub.follower_count DESC;
```

---

Getting the top N for ***multiple posts*** at once is a bit more complex. Detailed explanation in ***chapter 2a*** of this related answer:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

Comment: I added the suggested composite indexes and updated the initial post with a 4th attempt. That improved the average estimated cost, but the actual execution time doubled from #1. Also adding the index doubled #1's execution time so #1 and #4 have about the same execution time.

Comment: @RyanMcDonald: In #4 you join to `follower_count_mv` a 2nd time to get to `follower_count` for the outer `ORDER BY`. You also don't need `LIMIT 5` in the outer query. Consider the updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your query doesn't loop 10483 times, it loops once (loop=1) for each loop, but it has to sort 10483 rows first prior to discarding all but the first 5 rows.

Your last query was almost correct, except for the fact that you filter user_account by the users with greatest follower_count regardless of being involved in the discussion or not. Also, isn't this query returning the same user accounts? Because you're not using DISTINCT nor GROUP BY, and user_account has a one-to-many relationship to user_post_comment. Perhaps this will return more accurate results?

```
CREATE INDEX user_post_comment_post_id_user_id_idx ON user_post_comment (post_id, user_id);

SELECT user_account.*
FROM follower_count_mv
JOIN user_account ON (user_account.user_id = follower_count_mv.user_id)
WHERE follower_count_mv.user_id IN (
  SELECT user_id
  FROM user_post_comment
  WHERE post_id = '26c72242-7e3b-4982-92c5-021b622d7ecd'
  GROUP BY user_id)
ORDER BY follower_count_mv.follower_count DESC
LIMIT 5;
```