# PostgreSQL chooses a wrong order of Hash Join

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, join, execution-plan, postgresql-13

EXPLAIN shows that PostgreSQL chooses a bad plan for hash join. it should have first iterate by `tags_name_value_height2` in the table `tags` and use it to find corresponding `transactions.id`, but instead Postgres does a stupid reverse: it first iterates using `transactions_id` on `transactions`.

It's despite I do have all needed (composite) indexes.

How to make it work the right way?

```
explain
select *
from "transactions" 
join tags on transactions.id = tags.tx_id
where "tags"."name" = 'ZGF0YWJhc2U'
and "tags"."value" in ('c29sYXJ3ZWF2ZS10ZXN0bmV0LWFyY2hpdmU')
limit 2;
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=246323.53..246710.80 rows=2 width=1964)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=246323.53..12515067.96 rows=63359 width=1964)
         Hash Cond: ((transactions.id)::text = (tags.tx_id)::text)
         ->  Index Scan using transactions_id on transactions  (cost=0.56..10146177.49 rows=3822241 width=1803)
         ->  Hash  (cost=244045.99..244045.99 rows=63359 width=161)
               ->  Index Scan using tags_name_value_height2 on tags  (cost=0.94..244045.99 rows=63359 width=161)
                     Index Cond: ((name = 'ZGF0YWJhc2U'::text) AND (value = 'c29sYXJ3ZWF2ZS10ZXN0bmV0LWFyY2hpdmU'::text))
 JIT:
   Functions: 13
   Options: Inlining false, Optimization false, Expressions true, Deforming true
(10 rows)
```

Postgre 13. Maybe I should downngrade? Which version has good query hints?

```
arweave=# \d transactions
                                        Table "arweave.transactions"
    Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                  Default                  
---------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------
 id            | character varying(64)    |           | not null | 
 owner         | text                     |           |          | 
 tags          | jsonb                    |           |          | 
 target        | character varying(64)    |           |          | 
 quantity      | text                     |           |          | 
 reward        | text                     |           |          | 
 signature     | text                     |           |          | 
 last_tx       | text                     |           |          | 
 data_size     | bigint                   |           |          | 
 content_type  | character varying(255)   |           |          | 
 format        | integer                  |           |          | 
 height        | integer                  |           |          | 
 owner_address | character varying(255)   |           |          | 
 data_root     | character varying(64)    |           |          | 
 parent        | character varying(64)    |           |          | 
 created_at    | timestamp with time zone |           |          | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 app           | character varying(64)    |           |          | 
 domain        | character varying(64)    |           |          | 
 namespace     | character varying(64)    |           |          | 
 seq           | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('transactions_seq_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "transactions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (seq)
    "id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (id)
    "index_app_transactions" btree (app)
    "index_domain_transactions" btree (domain)
    "index_namespace_transactions" btree (namespace)
    "owner1" btree (seq, owner)
    "owner2" btree (seq DESC, owner)
    "transactions_height2" btree (height DESC, id DESC)
    "transactions_id" btree (id)
    "transactions_id_index" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (height, id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "tags" CONSTRAINT "tag_tx_id" FOREIGN KEY (height, tx_id) REFERENCES transactions(height, id)
    TABLE "tags" CONSTRAINT "tags_tx_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (tx_id) REFERENCES transactions(id)

arweave=# \d tags
                                        Table "arweave.tags"
    Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |              Default              
---------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------------
 tx_id         | character varying(64)    |           | not null | 
 owner_address | text                     |           |          | 
 height        | integer                  |           |          | 
 index         | integer                  |           | not null | 
 name          | text                     |           |          | 
 value         | text                     |           |          | 
 created_at    | timestamp with time zone |           |          | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 seq           | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('tags_seq_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "tags_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (seq)
    "tags_created_at" btree (created_at)
    "tags_height1" btree (height, tx_id)
    "tags_height2" btree (height DESC, tx_id DESC)
    "tags_name_height1" btree (name, height, tx_id)
    "tags_name_height2" btree (name, height DESC, tx_id DESC)
    "tags_name_value_height2" btree (name, value, height DESC, tx_id DESC)
    "tags_tx_id" btree (tx_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "tag_tx_id" FOREIGN KEY (height, tx_id) REFERENCES transactions(height, id)
    "tags_tx_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (tx_id) REFERENCES transactions(id)
```

(Note that the above are not yet very well constructed, but this should not affect this question.)

Comment: "it first iterates using `transactions_id` on `transactions`" -- what led you to this conclusion? By the way, have you tried an index on `tags (name, value, tx_id)`?

Comment: You have `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`. Is that intended? And you have `SELECT *`, returning all columns from `transactions` and `tags`. Is that intended? Please start with proper table and index definitions (`CREATE TABLE ...`) and tell us what the query is supposed to achieve *exactly*.

Comment: @mustaccio Yes, I told I have all the needed indexes including `"tags_name_height1" btree (name, height, tx_id)`. My conclusion is from to things: 1. it's irreasonable slowness; 2. `Index Scan using transactions_id on transactions` being first in the explain.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter This query is just for testing, so ORDER BY is not needed. Again `*` is for testing. I added the definitions. I try to make this mock query similar to real queries fast. I query a "document" with a certain name/value.

Comment: I understood what was the trouble: There was no relevant FK from `tags` to `transactions` and many duplicated and rows in `tags` that didn't refer to corresponding `transactions`. This was the reason of slowness. Should I remove my question?

Comment: You have `"tags_tx_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (tx_id) REFERENCES transactions(id)` - and use the same as join condition. Both are `character varying(64)` which makes for needlessly big indexes and is generally inefficient. Use the PK `transaction.seq` (integer) as target of the FK and query instead. Much more efficient. Also, `character varying(255)` is typically a misunderstanding in Postgres. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/137949/3684

Answer (score 1):

You are misreading the `EXPLAIN` output. Top nodes are executed *last*. In fact, the index `tags_name_value_height2` on `tags` is read first.

Imagine a tree. The more each node is indented, the earlier it is executed. Details in the manual in the chapter [**Using `EXPLAIN`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/using-explain.html).

Your query might be optimized, but we'd need proper definitions to say more.